# Secure boot + full disk encryption, should I sign the kernel?

Tags: linux, digital-signature, integrity, uefi, secure-boot

I'm redoing my laptop installation from scratch, and this time I want a full secure boot chain.

Here's what I did so far :

- Enroll my own keys in the UEFI firmware
- Sign my grub bootloader
- Full disk encryption (implying /boot is encrypted as well)

Many tutorials on the internet (not to say **all** tutorials) suggest that to accomplish a full secure boot, the kernel (initramfs I guess) should be signed, and the bootloader must make sure it's valid.

So my question is as follow : why sign the kernel/initramfs if the disk is already fully encrypted ?

According to [cryptsetup's FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), AES-XTS seems to be used by default to manage disk encryption.

As far as I know, unlike GCM, XTS does not provide any way to ensure data integrity. And this is probably why people on the internet suggest that the kernel should be signed to ensure a full secure boot.

Here's an interesting paragraph from [this Wikipedia page on disk encryption theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XTS_weaknesses) :

> XTS mode is susceptible to data manipulation and tampering, and applications must employ measures to detect modifications of data if manipulation and tampering is a concern: "...since there are no authentication tags then any ciphertext (original or modified by attacker) will be decrypted as some plaintext and there is no built-in mechanism to detect alterations. The best that can be done is to ensure that any alteration of the ciphertext will completely randomize the plaintext, and rely on the application that uses this transform to include sufficient redundancy in its plaintext to detect and discard such random plaintexts.

Even if an attacker were able to tamper with my encrypted kernel, grub would decrypt it into complete gibberish, therefore making it unbootable. Or at least it would break at some point, but it would be impossible (AFAIU) for an attacker to ensure its malicious cipher will turn into plaintext executable code. The goal of the secure boot being not to boot on untrusted software, why bother with kernel signature when full disk encryption already seems to meet those requirements ?

Comment: Rootkit can tamper with the kernel and kernel modules during the runtime of the OS. If it is signed, tampering will be detected on next boot.

Comment: True, but if a rootkit is running on my machine, I consider it's too late already. I guess it all depends on your threat model, but to me the secure boot only aims to protect against physical attacks. Considering I would need my private signing key available on my filesystem to sign the kernel+bootloader automatically on update, a potential rootkit could do the same.

Comment: Not always. Some malwares quietly compromise update manager to patch kernel and removes itself to avoid detection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If a rootkit manages to patch my kernel it means it already has root privileges on my machine, therefore it would also be able to access the private key I would use to sign the kernel on update. Maybe signing the kernel would prevent dumb rootkits from patching the kernel/bootloader, but an advanced one would sign its malicious patched kernel with my private key available in my /root folder and I would not realise it (because it's signed).

Comment: Private key that signs the kernel is never stored on the system. The reason a malware will rather quietly patch your kernel and remove itself than living on the system is to avoid detection because that would result in complete reinstall of the OS. A malware does not always require root. A vulnerability in the update manager can achieve the purpose without direct root access to the malware.

Comment: "Private key that signs the kernel is never stored on the system" -> How do you manage kernel/bootloader update then ? Most tutorials I found online (even the excellent ArchLinux wiki) seem to do that

Comment: Your question and body don't match. The question is about signing the kernel, the body asks about signing initrd. The latter is not necessary if /boot is encrypted.

Comment: The update manager receives the updated kernel image signature.

Comment: @defalt AFAIK no GNU/Linux distribution provides signed kernels.. Are you suggesting I should setup my own mirror to have a proper secure boot ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov well, correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like the same issue, the booloader will decrypt my LUKS partition where lies my initrd and kernel, what defalt is suggesting is that I should still sign both of them to enable the bootloader to ensure userspace didn't tamper with them

Comment: If you're concerned about userspace tampering with the initrd, you've got no redemption basically. Userspace may as well tamper with everything else (systemd init scripts, libraries, binaries, user autorun scripts, etc. etc. etc. etc.). And if you're really paranoid a person with physical access may install a HW keylogger and all your protections are worth nothing. And then there are laptops/PCs with spare DMA ports which allow to clandestinely install additional HW not detectable by your OS which is capable of reading your entire RAM which is enough to own your completely.

Comment: Fedora, RHEL and Ubuntu all come with the signed kernel and all its modules. I have a bog standard W10 laptop where I have secure boot enabled and I've not done anything else to make my Fedora run on it. Just installed and it was good to go. I used to install my own MOK certificate when I needed VirtualBox but then I just gave up.

Comment: If you're targeted by three-latter agencies you're SOL and all your protections are worthless. They won't even touch your laptop to retrieve all your passwords. This can be done remotely via e.g. the mains or your glass windows which perfectly pass all your key presses. They can drill a tiny hole in your wall while you're not at home: full video/audio/key presses.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I'm well aware that I won't be able to protect from any government with almost unlimited money. I'm more concerned about small APT actors or script kiddies using 1day exploits. I looked at Fedora's wiki about secure boot, that's awesome they achieved that as a default for everyone. So I guess if I wan't a full secure boot, I have to trust a third party with signing everything. Or you setup your own mirror which ships signed kernel/bootloader updates (but then how do you ensure secure boot of the machine which acts as a mirror ? ^^).

Comment: Anyway, I will stick to my signed bootloader and full disk encryption. This should prevent basic evil maid attacks so noone can hijack my uefi partition and steal my LUKS password (even though as you said, I do realize HW keyloggers are a thing).